# Shiny Leaflet - Highlight polygon

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a simple shiny-app with just a dropdown listing districts of Afghanistan and a leaflet map of the same. [image]

The shape file can be accessed at this [link](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/AFG_adm_shp.zip) - using AFG_adm2.shp from http://www.gadm.org/download

here's the app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

afg <- readOGR(dsn = "data", layer ="AFG_adm2", verbose = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test App"),
    selectInput("yours", choices = c("",afg$NAME_2), label = "Select Country:"),
    leafletOutput("mymap")

)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(afg) %>% #addTiles() %>%
       addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, color = "#00000", weight = 1) 
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want the functionality that when I select a district from the dropdown list, the **border fill of that district changes, and the setView function brings that district into focus**. Can someone help me out with the code? I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290142/leaflet-polygons-change-style-upon-choosing-location-from-a-shiny-dropdown-menu) post but can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `leafletProxy` to change the map when the user selects a district. You can add a slightly thicker red polygon on top of the one previously drawn to highlight it and use `setView` to move the view around.

This is what I would add:

```
proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap")

  observe({
    if(input$yours!=""){
      #get the selected polygon and extract the label point 
      selected_polygon <- subset(afg,afg$NAME_2==input$yours)
      polygon_labelPt <- selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]@labpt

      #remove any previously highlighted polygon
      proxy %>% removeShape("highlighted_polygon")

      #center the view on the polygon 
      proxy %>% setView(lng=polygon_labelPt[1],lat=polygon_labelPt[2],zoom=7)

      #add a slightly thicker red polygon on top of the selected one
      proxy %>% addPolylines(stroke=TRUE, weight = 2,color="red",data=selected_polygon,group="highlighted_polygon")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: that worked, but only for the reproducible example... There's an error when you declare "polygon_labelPt". Could you explain that to me so I can modify it? I don't understand that line of code: `polygon_labelPt <- selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]@labpt`

Comment: Okay, on debugging, selected_polygon@polygons is returning an empty list. So even calling `selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]` returns a subscript out of bounds error.  selected_polygon@bbox seems to have 2 sets of lat, long though. Can we use them?

Comment: the first `selected_polygon` line subsets the `afg` data to extract the polygon that has the name corresponding to what the user selected. Then the `polygon_labelPt` extracts the first polygon of the dataframe (`selected_polygon@polygons[[1]]`), then extracts the labpt (`@labpt`). The labpt is where the polygon should be labeled.

Comment: If selecte_polygon@polygons is an empty list, it means there are no polygons with the NAME2 the user selected so something is wrong in your full app. `bbox` is just a bounding matrix so you can't use that. see `?"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class"` for details

Comment: I've added what selected_polygons looks like in test case vs. my app in the post above.

Comment: it is empty because of this command `subset(afg,afg$NAME_2==input$yours)` returns an empty dataframe. This is because in your real map what you are trying to subset by does not exist in your `afg` data frame. Check your inputs etc to make sure user can only select polygons that have a NAME_2 that exists in your spatial data frame.

Comment: Also in your full app if doesn't look like your spatial dataframe has a `NAME_2` attribute so you have to change that in the subset command to match whatever is in the `input$yours` in your app.

Comment: I'm sorry for making such a silly error. I had changed it to match my app vars, just forgot to change the "id" of dropdown. Oops!

Comment: I have some polygons where `length(selected_polygon@polygons)` equals 2, that is a district is split into two. How do I highlight both of these sections - district parts?

Comment: you can try changing the `layerId` to `group` in the `addPolylines`

Comment: Awesome! That works! Also, changed `removeShape` to `clearGroup` to remove selected group/polygons.